# How to decide between AnnotationRetention.BINARY and AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME for Hilt Qualifiers?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, annotations, dagger-hilt

How do I know whether to use `AnnotationRetention.BINARY` or `AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME` for Hilt Qualifiers? E.g. look at this code from a [Medium Article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/create-an-application-coroutinescope-using-hilt-dd444e721528), where it seems to be even mixed (not sure if the author intended that):

```
// CoroutinesQualifiers.kt file

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class DefaultDispatcher

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class IoDispatcher

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class MainDispatcher

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)   <================== once binary
@Qualifier
annotation class MainImmediateDispatcher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Hilt but looks like it's just an Android extention of Dagger2.

So, lets start from options in `AnnotationRetention` enum they kind of go from the weakest to strongest

- `SOURCE` annotation won't be retained in the compiled code, it pretty much present at compile time but then stripped off
- `BINARY` will be available in compiled code but not visible via reflection
- `RUNTIME` will be retained in compiled code and can be read via reflection

Dagger2 does not use reflection in order to resolve dependencies. Instead it builds dependency graph during build time via `kapt`.

In Hilt's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) on **AndroidDevelopers.com** they use the `AnnotationRetention.BINARY` policy.

Though taking into account what I wrote above, it should be totally okay to use `AnnotationRetention.SOURCE` as it is only important to have the annotation present during the graph generation. And it works perfectly fine for me.